How to pass array into vec4 main() in .glsl OpenRV?
I am trying to create a custom GLSL node in OpenRV. When I passed the vec2 lassoPoints[256] into the main function, it showed a syntax error like this in the OpenRV console.
ERROR: compiling shader main: 
ERROR: 0(3) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected identifier, expecting ',' or ';' at token "_1" 
ERROR: 0(90) : error C1068: array index out of bounds 
ERROR: 0(90) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected identifier, expecting ')' at token "_1" 
ERROR: ----- source follows ---- 
ERROR: 1: #version 150 
ERROR: 2: #extension GL_ARB_texture_rectangle : require 
ERROR: 3: uniform vec2 lassoPoints[256]_1; 

ERROR: main failed to compile. Cannot build program 
ERROR: failed to compile/select GL program: ERROR: failed to select the GL program 

This is my code .gto and .glsl file to create a custom GLSL node in OpenRV.
lasso.gto
GTOa (4)

Lasso : IPNodeDefinition (1)
{
    node
    {
        string evaluationType = "color"
        string defaultName = "Lasso"
        string creator = ""
        string documentation = ""
        int userVisible = 1
    }
    render
    {
        int intermediate = 0
    }
    function
    {
        string name = "main"
        string type = "color"
        string glsl = "file://${HERE}/lasso.glsl"
    }
    parameters
    {
        float[2] lassoPoints = [ [0.0 0.0] ]
        int pointCount = [0]
   
    }
    documentation
    {
        string summary = ""
        string html = ""
    }
    icon
    {
        byte RGBA = [ ]
    }
}

lasso.glsl
vec4 main(
    const in inputImage in0,
    const in vec2 lassoPoints[256],
    const in int pointCount)
{
    vec4 P = in0();
    return P;
}

Now, I try to use sampler1D and sampler2D, etc. It also has errors.
vec4 main(
    const in inputImage in0,
    const in sampler1D lassoPoints,
    const in int pointCount)
{
    vec4 P = in0();
    return P;
}

I don't know what is incompatible type for parameter #2 (""). type error?
ERROR: compiling shader main: 
ERROR: 0(89) : error C1102: incompatible type for parameter #2 ("") 
ERROR: 0(89) : error C1103: too few parameters in function call 
ERROR: ----- source follows ---- 
ERROR: 1: #version 150 
ERROR: 2: #extension GL_ARB_texture_rectangle : require 
ERROR: 3: uniform int pointCount_1; 
ERROR: 4: uniform mat4 M_1; 
ERROR: 5: uniform sampler2DRect RGBA_sampler_1; 
ERROR: 6: uniform vec2 samplerSize_1; 
ERROR: 7: uniform float orientation_1; 
ERROR: 8: in vec2 TexCoord0; 
ERROR: 9: out vec4 FragColor; 

I don't know how to pass the array into vec4 main() in .glsl OpenRV.
Help me please.
